# Multiple instances of SignalR JS hub proxy, implementing function callback multiple times

Tags: javascript, signalr

Is it possible to create multiple instances of SignalR hub proxy or to implement same function callback multiple times?

If I write something like:

```
var obj1 = function() 
{
    var someHub = $.connection.someHub;
    var self = this;

    someHub.client.someFunction = function(item){

        //do something
    };
}

var obj2 = function() 
{
    var someHub = $.connection.someHub;
    var self = this;

    someHub.client.someFunction = function(item){

        //do something else
    };
}
```

Which implemenetation of `someFunction` would be called? 
Is it possible to implement same function twice and have both implementations executed?

Comment: Two instances of the same websocket? Websockets use "push" techonology, so it would just be duplication at the same time why not logically separate out or duplicate the response?

Comment: The only difference would be that they connect to separate ports server side (although this is abstracted in signalr). Aside from that they would both be called with the same data injected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var someHub = $.connection.someHub;

someHub.on('someFunction', function (item) { /* ... */ });
someHub.on('someFunction', function (item) { /* ... */ });
```

In the above code, both callbacks will be invoked in the order they were attached for each call to `Clients.*.someFunction` on the server.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy

Comment: In JS, `someHub.client.someFunction === someHub.client['someFunction']`. The property syntax is nearly as vulnerable to typos as strings. No error would be raised if you wrote `someHub.client.someFuntcion = function (item) { /* ... */ }`.